# Unable to Apply Catalog Price Rules for huze amount of data in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am having issues with getting a Magento store to apply catalog price rules. My data base is huze having the 200000 of the products, and I am trying to apply a global discount to most of the products in the store.

We have set up the price rule, but when can not apply it it just spins and spins and hangs, without applying any prices. I have tried to do it with the some custom code given below:

The Steps which I follow are given below:

I have created a file with the name rule apply and the code below:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");

// Let's include mage.php file
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);

// Initialize the magento
Mage::app('default');

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

        try {
            Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->applyAll();
            Mage::app()->removeCache('catalog_rules_dirty');
            echo Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('The rules have been applied.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo Mage::helper('catalogrule')->__('Unable to apply rules.');
            print_r($e);
        }

?>
```

I have runs this file by using the ssh but after more than 8 hours it shows the Error: Broken pipe.

Please suggest me the way how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply particular rule than you cna do it like below:

```
<?php 
    $catalogPriceRule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(7);
    $catalogPriceRule->applyAll();
?>
```

Or if you want to appyall rules than you can do like below:

```
<?php
    $catalogPriceRuleCollection = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->getCollection();
    foreach($catalogPriceRuleCollection as $ruleobj)
    {
       $ruleobj->applyAll();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hello Hardik, Thanks for your reply I have done all these but can not get the success. Please let me know if there is any other solutions.